# Migrating jquery code from stateless react component to es6 component

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a component that renders a Boostrap modal. I want to add a class to another button when the modal appears, so I have the below code:

```
const AddContact = () => {
  }
  $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('.add-button').addClass("orange-btn")
  })
  return (
//modal
...
}
```

How do I do the same thing with a es6 component? I tried to put the jquery code into the constructor but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you closed the function's bracket early in 2nd line. Try with this.

```
const AddContact = () => {
  $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('.add-button').addClass("orange-btn")
  })
  return (
//modal
...
}
```

Hope this will help.